# Cron job in ruby on rails not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cron, whenever, cron-task

I followed the railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby but I cant seem to make it worked.

- I have schedule.rb in my config.
- I wished to refresh my Database.count everyday in my homepage.
- I cannot find the deploy.rb in my folder. Where is it?

For testing purpose, I changed it to every 2 seconds.

[schedule.rb]

```
every '2 * * * *' do
  rake "pages_controller:home"
end
```

[pages_controller.rb]

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
def home
  @title = "Home"
  @companies = Company.find(:all, :limit => 20)
  @count = Company.count

end
```

I have put

```
 gem 'whenever', :require => false
```

in my gemfile. What have gone missing?

Comment: You say you're missing the deploy.rb -- have you installed and configured capistrano?

Comment: I don't have it. Do I need to manually create a deploy.rb in config?

Answer (score 0):

I have used cron job but i run it as rake task please you can try it

```
  every 3.minutes do
   set :environment, 'development'
   rake "daily",:output => {:error => 'error.log', :standard => 'cron.log'}
  end
```

And my task is like

```
  require 'rubygems'

  task :daily => :environment do
    puts "i am fine"
    # do your code
  end
```

If cron job run fine then there will be nothing in cron.log.Otherwise it will show you if

any error  occurs and this file will be generate in your app root directory.

try it..

Comment: what file is your task :daily => :environment in?

Answer (score 0):

So... Couple things.

1. You need a Capfile and a config/deploy.rb to deploy your code using Capistrano and Whenver. You get this by running `capify .` ... You should most likely watch the railscast on capistrano deployment
2. Whenever is using configured like:

schedule.rb

```
every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do 
  runner 'Rails.cache.clear'
end
```

I really don't think `rake "pages_controller:home` is going to work unless this is something you've already created elsewhere. I'm further assuming you are caching this page, and that's why you need to refresh the cache.

Finally, you're setting your environment to development, which makes me think you are not deploying this, but instead just wanting to reset the cached home page... So just run `rake cache:clear`

Comment: in `block in initialize': undefined local variable or method `clear' for #<Whenever::JobList:0x000001012c2c78> (NameError)
 from /Users/amysukumunu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/whenever-0.7.3/lib/whenever/job_list.rb:38:in `every'